# MySQL php query printing to screen instead of creating a force download csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am having issues with trying to create a force download csv file. Instead the data is being printed out on the screen.  I have kept this excel export script in a separate php file and have included it on another php file.

Here is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$caseStudyTable;
$result =  mysql_query($query);

if(!$result)
{
    $message = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}


// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');


mysql_close($connect);

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) fputcsv($output, $row);


exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Content-Type: application/csv` you should use `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: I tried adding that in and it still prints the data onto the screen instead of a download.

Comment: You should have replaced the line in your code with this one. Not adding it.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant that I replaced it with that line.

Comment: Yes I get the same thing.

Comment: I figured out what wasn't working.  The code with your add was perfectly fine.  I must have been over riding the header function with some echo or window above the include.  Once I changed the php file to a hyperlink everything worked!